# Java Error: Issue with for loop which should convert every content of a string array to a float array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to program a calculator in java. It should be possible for me, to let one row entered in the console calculate at once. With ".split" and regex I am separating operators and values.

Somehow this works, when I convert only one element of an array at time. But then I would need to be specific to every case (element 0, element1, element2 etc.) So I thought it would be possible, to take a variable in a loop instead of a number a time.

This is what works:

```
zahl1 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[0]);
zahl2 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[1]);
```

Would be very thankful, if someone could give me some advice in this..

but the loop in the loop of the following code

```
package parserrechner;
import java.util.*;

public class ParserRechner
{
    public static String rechnung,
                         regexCheck = "(([\\+ \\- \\* \\/]))";
    public static float ergebnis;

    public static String[] Zeichenkette;
    public static float[] konventiert;

    public static Scanner eingabe = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Geben Sie Ihre Rechnung auf einer Zeile ein z.B. 4+7/8 [+, -, *, /]");
        rechnung = eingabe.next();

        Zeichenkette = rechnung.split(regexCheck);

        int i = 0;
        while(i <= Zeichenkette.length)
        {
            konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
            i++;
        }

        //float zahl1 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[0]);  /////without loop
        //float zahl2 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[1]);  /////

        if(rechnung.contains("+"))
        {
            for(int counter = 0; counter <= konventiert.length; counter++)
            {
                ergebnis = ergebnis + konventiert[counter];
            }
        }
 /*     else if(rechnung.contains("-")) /////
        {
            ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
        }
        else if(rechnung.contains("*")) //////
        {
            ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
        }
        else if(rechnung.contains("/"))  /////without loop, not finished
        {
            ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;    /////
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Falsches Format."); //////
        }
*/
        System.out.println(ergebnis);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? if any?

Comment: @jipr311 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at rechnerparser.RechnerParser.main(RechnerParser.java:32)"

Comment: chek my answer bitte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static float[] konventiert;
```

is never initialized. When executing `konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);` It will try to go to the i index on an array that is still a nullpointer.

Try

```
konventiert = new float[Zeichenkette.length];
```

before the loop.

**Also

```
int i = 0;
        while(i <= Zeichenkette.length)
        {
            konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

should rather be

```
int i = 0;
            while(i < Zeichenkette.length)
            {
                konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
                i++;
            }
```

and

```
for(int counter = 0; counter <= konventiert.length; counter++)
            {
                ergebnis = ergebnis + konventiert[counter];
            }
```

should be

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < konventiert.length; counter++)
            {
                ergebnis = ergebnis + konventiert[counter];
            }
```

Comment: You are also making the mistake in the loop by using <= konventiert.length this should be <.
When the array has length 5 for example, the array will be out of bounds at array[5] since array [4] is the last index. Always remember that java is zero based. :)

Comment: "thanks to everyone" would include upvoting the answers that were helpful - once  have enough reputation to do so ;-)

Comment: @Jan I would like to vote your answer but i need 2 more reputation points :)

Comment: Too bad - I guess you need to ask another question sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
regexCheck = "(([\\+, \\-, \\* \\/]))";
```

This splits at every occurence of '+','-','/','*' **and** ' ' and ','. As floating numbers in German would be given as 1,23 and so on, your regex would split them up I guess. Try

```
regexCheck = "[\\+\\-\\*/]";
```

instead.

Here's the different answers combined (Fixes for regex, array init, loop check)

```
    Zeichenkette = rechnung.split(regexCheck);
    konventiert = new Float[Zeichenkette.length];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < Zeichenkette.length) {
        konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
        i++;
    }

    if(rechnung.contains("+")) {
        for(int counter = 0; counter < konventiert.length; counter++) {           
            ergebnis +=  konventiert[counter];
        }
    }
```

You could even condense it down to **one** loop and skip the konvertiert array alltogether:

```
   if(rechnung.contains("+")) {
      for(int counter = 0; counter < Zeichenkette.length; counter++) {           
            ergebnis +=  Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[counter]);
        }
   }
```

Comment: yes that's not right but that's not my problem. It doesn't convert in the loop  from string[] Zeichenkette to float[] konvertiert. that's the problem

Comment: Yes. Put together both answers and you'll be fine I think. I missed that array not created before the loop.

Comment: Tried to combine the answers into one hopefully working piece of code - the <= issue you had twice, plus the regex and the not initialized array.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting and out of index because of:
1.- your array was never initialized, and 
2-. your conditional is using "**<=**" instead of "**<**"

I updated your main method, try again and let me know...

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Geben Sie Ihre Rechnung auf einer Zeile ein z.B. 4+7/8 [+, -, *, /]");
    rechnung = eingabe.next();

    Zeichenkette = rechnung.split(regexCheck);
    konventiert = new float[Zeichenkette.length];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Zeichenkette.length) {
        konventiert[i] = Float.parseFloat(Zeichenkette[i]);
        i++;
    }

    // float zahl1 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[0]); /////without loop
    // float zahl2 = Float.valueOf(Zeichenkette[1]); /////

    if (rechnung.contains("+")) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < konventiert.length; counter++) {
            ergebnis = ergebnis + konventiert[counter];
        }
    }
    /*
     * else if(rechnung.contains("-")) /////
     * {
     * ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
     * }
     * else if(rechnung.contains("*")) //////
     * {
     * ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
     * }
     * else if(rechnung.contains("/")) /////without loop, not finished
     * {
     * ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2; /////
     * }
     * else
     * {
     * System.out.println("Falsches Format."); //////
     * }
     */
    System.out.println(ergebnis);
}
```

Comment: i tried all the answers but still not workin. still getting the error message